# Flash Game : getTimer unaccurate

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, time, timer

I'm working on the game. The gameplay is based on a really small time lapse (you have only 5 secondes to do an action).
My timer works great in Flash Player, i DO have 5 secondes. In a web browser (firefox, safari ..) the 5 seconds timer is now 8 seconds.

How to solve this ? 
Here is my code where i display the time:

```
private function updateTimer(e:TimerEvent) 
{
    if (this.timer.currentCount < 500) 
    {
         var centiemes:int = 100 - Math.floor(this.timer.currentCount) % 100;
         var secondes:int = 4 - Math.floor(this.timer.currentCount / 100) % 60;

         this.txtTemps.text = ToolBox.zeroFill(secondes.toString(), 2) + ":" +  ToolBox.zeroFill(centiemes.toString(), 2);
    }
    else 
    {
          this.txtTemps.text = "00:00";
          this.timer.stop();;
     }
 }
```

Thanks you !

Comment: Same problem as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014009/as3-how-accurate-are-the-gettimer-method-and-the-timer-class

Comment: No, it seems that Adobe must have correct this. It's seems that the Timer as been put because the framerate was based on processor and can be different.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Timer & setInterval are not accurate.

To get accurate time, you can either work with calculating delta between frames & time or you can use the technique that the Audiotool team uses and work with an audio file. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1859638/803727) and [here](http://glossar.hs-augsburg.de/Konstanter_Timer_(ActionScript_3)).

Comment: I will look up on those links ! Thanks !