# Accurately measuring time delta

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

As I understand, `getTimer()` is very inaccurate - on my own machine it always returns a value which is a product of ~16. (16, 33, 50, etc.)

Is there a simple and efficient way to more accurately measure the time difference (delta) between two separate calls in my program?

I have looked for information on the subject, but most of what I find seems unnecessarily elaborate.

Comment: where/when are you calling `getTimer()`? at what fps is your app running? seems like you're calling it in an `ENTER_FRAME` listener at about 62 fps - seems pretty accurate then ;)

Answer (score 4):

Edit:
Digging further, and with help from a colleague, apparently you can get good timing by using Sound. Try creating a new `Sound` object, playing it and then extract the `position` property from the returned `SoundChannel`-object. There are also some good ideas here: [Stack Overflow - Accurate BPM event listener in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858660/accurate-bpm-event-listener-in-as3)

<strike>I haven't tried this, but you could try using the `Date` class and extracting the `milliseconds` property from it, and use that. I'm unsure of how accurate that is, in comparison to getTimer, but it might be worth experimenting with. See the [AS3: Date documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) for more information. Note however that the Date doc explicitly says this:</strike> *To compute relative time or time elapsed, see the getTimer() method in the flash.utils package.*

Other than that I think you're stuck with using getTimer, and the data it returns depends on your current OS/browser. You probably checked these links out already, otherwise they'll help explain the problem:

[Tinic Uro - Frame Rates in the Flash Player](http://www.kaourantin.net/2006/05/frame-rates-in-flash-player.html)

[Stack Overflow - AS3: How accurate are the getTimer() method and the Timer class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014009/as3-how-accurate-are-the-gettimer-method-and-the-timer-class)